# How to load registers on emacs startup?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Is there anyway to load a list predefined registers on emacs startup instead of crazily inserting them manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call:

```el
(set-register REGISTER VALUE)
```

For the typical interactive usage, `REGISTER` will be a char, such as `?a`

For programmatic usage, registers can be anything comparable with `eq` (e.g. chars/integers, 'symbols and :keywords all work; strings do not). If you want to use registers *without* conflicting with their interactive usage, it's better to not use a char.